# Why does the change in this property not trigger a watch in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to figure out why a property that is changed is not triggering a watch in Vue.

I have 2 components Parent and Child.

Child has as 1 Prop (item) and item has 4 properties: id, text, isImportant, isCool.

The Parent has 2 lists that are populated using two computed properties which return arrays, one where the items's "isImportant" == TRUE and the other where "isImportant" is FALSE.

In the Child, isImportant and isCool are both bound to input[type=checkbox] elements.

I have a watch (deep) set to respond to changes in the item prop of the Child.

Changing "isCool" triggers the watch while "isImportant" does not.

Changing isImportant does update the collection and the property is updated but it does not trigger the "watch".

It seems to be related to the computed property but not sure why?

https://jsfiddle.net/dclaysmith/y54b0mrq/

```
Vue.component('todo', {
    props: {
        item: Object
    },
    template: `
        <label>
            {{ item.text }}
          <input type="checkbox"
            v-model="item.isImportant">
            Is Important?
          <input type="checkbox"
            v-model="item.isTicked">
            Is Cool?
      </label>`,
    watch: {
      item: {
        handler: function (a, b) {
            alert('Changed!')
        },
        deep: true
      },
      'item.isImportant': function (a, b) {
        alert('Changed!')
      }
    },
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: `
<div id="app">
  <h2>Important:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="item in important">
      <todo :item="item" :key="item.id"></todo>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <br>
  <h2>Not Important:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="item in notImportant">
      <todo :item="item" :key="item.id"></todo>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
    `,
    data: {
      todos: [
        { id: 1, text: "Learn JavaScript", isImportant: false, isTicked: false },
        { id: 2, text: "Learn Vue", isImportant: true, isTicked: false },
        { id: 3, text: "Play around in JSFiddle", isImportant: true, isTicked: false },
        { id: 4, text: "Build something awesome", isImportant: true, isTicked: false }
      ]
        },
    computed: {
      important: function () {
        return this.todos.filter(function(todo) {
          return (todo.isImportant == true);
        });
      },
      notImportant: function () {
        return this.todos.filter(function(todo) {
          return (todo.isImportant != true);
        });
      }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the change to `isImportant` isn't caught by the component, is that when you change `isImportant`, the component is removed, because the todo-item is moved from one list to the other.

If you have just one list of all todo's (`<li v-for="item in todos">`), both listeners trigger just fine.